# OnPhotoCaptureCreated not called when running in Hololens

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens

I am trying to make an app that would capture photos in Hololens. I have followed the tutorial and almost copied the tutorial code. When I run it on my computer in Unity it works and takes a photo with my webcam. But when I run it on Hololens it doesn't work.
My problematic part of code is here:

```
void Start() {

startHeadPosition = Camera.main.transform.position;
newHeadPosition = startHeadPosition;
dIndikator.text = "";

CreateScene("Test");


Debug.Log("\n Taking picture \n");
PhotoCapture.CreateAsync(false, OnPhotoCaptureCreated);
Debug.Log("\n Debug 2 \n");
}

void OnPhotoCaptureCreated(PhotoCapture captureObject)
{
Debug.Log("\n Debug 1 \n");
photoCaptureObject = captureObject;

m_cameraResolution = PhotoCapture.SupportedResolutions.OrderByDescending((res) => res.width * res.height).Last();

CameraParameters c = new CameraParameters();
c.hologramOpacity = 0.0f;
c.cameraResolutionWidth = m_cameraResolution.width;
c.cameraResolutionHeight = m_cameraResolution.height;
c.pixelFormat = CapturePixelFormat.JPEG;

Debug.Log("\n PhotoModeStarted \n");

captureObject.StartPhotoModeAsync(c, OnPhotoModeStarted);
}
```

In Unity the log looks like this:

Taking picture

Debug 2

Debug 1

PhotoModeStarted

But when in Hololens I get only:

Taking picture

Debug 2

So it looks like it doesn't even enter the OnPhotoCaptureCreated. I have set capabilities to the camera and microphone and made sure I have them in the manifest file so I don't have any idea what would have caused this problem. I also made sure to have camera enabled for the app in the Hololens privacy settings.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end it was probably a problem of that one Hololens device. It worked on other ones so we've set it back to factory setting and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the callback methof for `PhotoCapture.CreateAsync` is not executed because there is no permission to use the camera from your app.

Go to `Settings/Privacy/Camera/` and enable `"Let apps use my camera"`

Comment: I already have that enabled and all capabilities (webcam, microphone) set.

Comment: What happens when you pass `true` instead of `false` to the `CreateAsync` function?

Comment: The boolean in CreateAsync is for showing holograms on the picture.